# AngularJs CheckBox conundrum

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

My view has

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" ng-model="campaign.paused"  
       ng-click="CampaignPauseClicked(campaign, $event)" />

<p>campaign.paused == {{campaign.paused}}</p>
```

with the `<p>` being for debugging. It shows `false`, as it shoudl, given the data, but in the controller

```
$scope.CampaignPauseClicked = function(campaign, $event)
{
    campaign.paused = ! campaign.paused;
```

when I breakpoint on the first code line, the value of `campaign.paused`      is `true` (!).

I have searched the code and `campaign.paused` is not being written elsewhere.

Any idea what could be happening here?

---

[Update] I am using an `ng-click` fucntion, which I have not shown in its entirity, because I need it to "swallow" the `$event` and prevent it from propogating to the parent.

Comment: since you are doing `campaign.paused = ! campaign.paused;` its normal for `campaign.paused` to be true

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your comment (my bad). That statement is supposed to toggle the current value. Do you see some wrong in it?

Comment: its simple. when you are clicking on the checkbox your model `ng-model="campaign.paused"` gets the value of `true` this is done automatically because of Angular. What you do in your code is to reverse that and have true when the checkbox is not clicked and false when it is. It looks that you need to read on the ng-model directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `ng-model` is updating the value when you click the checkbox. You're undoing what Angular is doing for you.

If you want to do it by yourself in your `$scope.CampaignPauseClicked` function, remove the `ng-model` part from the html.

Otherwise, you can let Angular do its thing, leave the `ng-model="campaign.paused"` clause, and remove the first line from your `ng-click` callback.

Comment: Lolx!! How could I make such a clueless n00b mistake?? Of course, your correct (+1 and the answer). There is no need for me to toggle the checked state, since the `ng-model` is doing that for me. How embarrassing :-/

Answer (score 1):

Also you can replace the `ng-click` with the `ng-change` directive since you are using a checkbox.
[ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) will run everytime the checkbox state is changed (checked/unchecked)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check_box" ng-model="campaign.paused"  
       ng-change="CampaignPauseChanged ($event)" />

<p>campaign.paused == {{campaign.paused}}</p>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.CampaignPauseChanged = function(event)
{
    console.log(campaign.paused)
    console.log(event)
}
```

Another option would be the `ng-checked` [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) here is an example in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9IDuECMFfeKxw53tXVu8?p=preview). As you can clearly see the checkbox model returns true only if it is checked.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I apoliogze because I did not explain that I need to use `ng-clck` - I have now updated the question to explain why.